# Can I get relating resources by SharePoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

There is an `API` to get relating resources in OData, the Url likes this: `http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(34wtn2c0hkuk5ekg0pjr513b))/TripPinServiceRW/People('russellwhyte')/Trips(0)`.

Can I use it in SharePoint, or is there any other API likes this to get relating resources?

Thank you for your advises!

*P.S. I know that I can use `Lookup` field and `Expand` to get resources, but it cannot meet my requirements.*

I have `List A` and `List B`, `List B` is a task list. so how can I get relating tasks when I get each item form `List A` by one request?

I know that I can use `expand`, likes `~/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List B')/items?$select=ListA/Title,ListA/Field0...&$expand=ListA`. But I don't want to get data from `List B`, cause I need to filter data by current user's permissions in `List A`.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the example of related resource you are trying to get in SharePoint?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev Hello Vadim, I've updated my question, thank you!

Comment: Is there a lookup field that relates List A to List B? Also, are you trying to iterate over every task in List B?

Comment: @MickB Yes, List B is a task list, so there is a column named Related Item, and I insert a lookup column in List B to store the Title in List A. I'm only trying to get all relating tasks when I get each item from List A, and I want to get them by one http request. Not iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Since the lookup is in List B and you are querying List A there is not one request to retrieve the info you are looking for. If the Lookup was in List A you could see all the List B items. Without that, you need to first query all the List B items and return all the List A item ID's, then query List A.

`_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List B')?$select=lookupColumn/Id&$expand=lookupColumn/Id`

`_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List A')?$filter=Id eq 'someID' or Id eq 'someID2'`

Comment: Yes, I knew this way. But I'm trying to find a way to get data from List A and List B via 1 request only. Thank you!